# Failing to create new table in Web SQL Database

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, web-sql

I've been trying to add a table to my database, and for some reason it isn't working.

Here's the code in question

```
var db = openDatabase('movies', '1.0', 'movies database', 50 * 1024 * 1024);


$("#newplayers").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //The two variables are called from the input of the player, denoting Company Name and Player Name.
    companyName = document.getElementById("companyname").value;
    playerName = document.getElementById("playername").value;
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE userinfo (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, player TEXT, company TEXT)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO userinfo (player,company) VAUES (?, ?)', [playerName,companyName]);
    });
    document.getElementById("company").innerHTML = companyName;
});
```

What baffles me further is that elsewhere in the code I created a table flawlessly, and using what appears to be the same code isn't bringing the same results.

Comment: I should mention, I know that the submit function is working fine, as everything else except creating the table works. there is also no error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the SQL execute Insert statement

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO userinfo (player,company) VAUES (?, ?)', [playerName,companyName]);
```

you have `"VAUES"` (instead of VALUES)

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I missed that, I poured over that code for two hours...Thank you so much! It worked!